# Unable to reference FSharp.Core in LINQPad when referencing the FSharp.Data package

Tags: f#, linqpad

I am trying to use [LINQPAD 4](http://www.linqpad.net/) to test HTML Parsing using F# and the FSharp.Data library. I proceeded as follows:

- I created a new F# Program in LINQPad
- Pressed F4 and added FSharp.Data as a NuGet package

I then tried to compile and run the following program in LINQPad

```
open FSharp.Data    
let results = HtmlDocument.Load("http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=FSharp.Data")
results.Dump()
```

- This returns a error telling me I need the assembly **'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0.**
- I then press F4 and add the required FSharp.Core assembly
- I now get the following compiler error :

> error FS1222: When mscorlib.dll or FSharp.Core.dll is explicitly
>   referenced the --noframework option must also be passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with LINQPad which will be addressed in the next release (At the time of posting I was using LINQPad Premium 4.51.03 and .NET version 4.5.1 running on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit)

[See this post on the LINQPad forum](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/711/unable-to-reference-fsharp-core-in-linqpad-when-referencing-the-fsharp-data-package)